# USB Mouse doesn't work after turning on Laptop

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I have a USB mouse attached to my laptop which does not work when I switch my laptop on. I have to unplug it and plug it back in before it works.

When I do this no driver installation occurs (presumably because it has already done this) the usual beep sound does occur and the mouse starts working again.

If my laptop goes to sleep I can move the mouse and the laptop comes back to life. In fact it works perfectly apart from this annoying niggle on startup.

Can anyone shed any light as to why I have to keep unplugging and plugging my mouse back on startup?

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 (64 bit) on a Toshiba Satellite L755-1LL Laptop.

Comment: Does the issue persist when you wake up from hibernation?

Comment: @phw no, it doesn't. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its a problem with your mouse driver. 
Uninstall and reinstall should fix your problem.
`Control-Panel > System > Hardware>Device manager`

If Your problem still occurs, probably its a power situation. You could try to "**Power Cycle**" the laptop to make sure this insn't the case.

First remove the battery and turn on your laptop using just the AC adapter/recharger. 
This is " Power Cycling", as it removes the DC power from your laptop and allows the AC power to run its course.

If it works that way ,  then just play with it for a few minutes , and then ShutDown.

Place your battery back in and turn on your laptop.

Hope it helps !!!